# Regular expression syntax problem

Tags: php, regex

```
$pattern='`<a\s+[^>]*(href=([\'\"]).*\\2)[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>`isU';
```

And I want to change `([^<]*)` this to search for `</a>` not only `<` cause `<img>` tag could be inside `<a>` tag.

Can anyone help, I'm lousy at regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `([^<]*)`to a ungreedy match all `(.*?)` might do the trick

Comment: @yes123 while i do agree, he did ask for a regex fix.

Comment: then you should reply him to not use regex

Comment: @Mick I second that. Regex is not the tool to parse HTML, and recommending it only encourages people to try it nevertheless.

Comment: No downvote from me, BUT regex is just the wrong tool for this job. Showing the OP the correct way to solve his problem is much more helpful to him.

Comment: Noted, and thanks for the critique - Not that seasoned with Stackoverflow yet but i'll surely keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a PHP parser to do this. I wouldn't use Regex at all.

You can try:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Although I think PHP has a DOM parser built in.

Answer (score 0):

`([^<]*)` could be changed to `((?:[^<]|<(?!/a>))*)`, which uses a negative lookahead to match non-`<` characters or `<` characters which are not followed by `/a>`. See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?2tvuk).

**HOWEVER**, as stated many times over already, this is not a good way to parse HTML. Firstly, it's horribly inefficient, and secondly, what happens if you have nested tags, such as `<a><a></a></a>`? While this may not happen with hyperlinks, it's common among many other HTML elements.